# Conformal map onto a circle, from an identification space composed of five square regions.

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry, meshing

I am looking to derive a conformal map for the problem illustrated in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NeJMZ.jpg) image. I've read a bit about how to map a square onto a circle, but I'm struggling to extend the concepts for the domain at hand. I don't have a rigorous mathematical background (mech. engineer in computational fluid dynamics), so I would appreciate if someone here could advise me on the route that I should take in order to derive such a conformal mapping.

The end application is to generate a smooth computational mesh that looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXp57.jpg). I have generated a mesh like this using other means, but the smoothness of the mesh vertices is not sufficient for extremely fine meshes. This results in spurious oscillations in the numerical problem I am trying to solve.

Comment: You need to find out about [Schwarz-Christoffel mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz%E2%80%93Christoffel_mapping).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I have read a bit about how to use Christoffel-Schwartz for mapping a square onto a circle. But I do not know how to extend it to the current context.

Comment: @Somos, also, how do I account for the fact that some edges are mapped onto circular segments? Does Christoffel-Schwartz accommodate for that?

Comment: I suggest to map the region you are interested in, which is a polygon, onto a half plane. Then hat can be easily mapped onto a disk.

Answer (score 1):

This question is a couple of years old, but so far no analytic solutions have been offered.

If you're willing to consider a computational solution, You might want to try this [Boundary First Flattening](https://geometrycollective.github.io/boundary-first-flattening/) app.

> Boundary First Flattening (BFF) is a free and open source application
> for surface parameterization. Unlike other tools for UV mapping, BFF
> allows free-form editing of the flattened mesh, providing users direct
> control over the shape of the flattened domain—rather than being stuck
> with whatever the software provides. The initial flattening is fully
> automatic, with distortion mathematically guaranteed to be as low or
> lower than any other conformal mapping tool. The tool also provides
> some state-of-the art flattening techniques not available in standard
> UV mapping software such as cone singularities, which can dramatically
> reduce area distortion, and seamless maps, which help eliminate
> artifacts by ensuring identical texture resolution across all cuts.
> BFF is highly optimized, allowing interactive editing of meshes with
> millions of triangles.
>
> The BFF application is based on the paper, “Boundary First Flattening”
> by Rohan Sawhney and Keenan Crane.

You can supply it with a mesh model of a cube that is missing one of its faces.  This is a surface with a boundary.
You should be able to use the app to create a mesh whose boundary is a circle corresponding to the boundary of your model and whose interior is a nearly conformal flattening of the remaining five faces of the cube.